# trying to understand what this code is doing with the $PSBoundParameters object

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm playing with proxy functions and I would like to completely understand all the code I am looking at.

Given this:

```
$MetaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData
    (Get-Command Get-ChildItem)
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($MetaData)
```

Here is a snippet of code from that output I don't understand:

```
begin
{
    try {

        $outBuffer = $null

        if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer)) {
            $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
        }
```

I'm just curious about whats happening with the PSBoundParameters here. Is it just testing if it can get a handle to the outbuffer? Why?

Edit: Other things I don't get with this is the way it is calling TryGetValue because looking at the definition:

```
($PSBoundParameters | gm -Name trygetvalue).definition

bool TryGetValue(string key, [ref] System.Object value),
bool IDictionary[string,Object].TryGetValue(string key, [ref] System.Object value),
bool IReadOnlyDictionary[string,Object].TryGetValue(string key, [ref] System.Object value)
```

It looks like it needs a 3rd argument: `(string key, [ref]System.Object valueToBeStored)`

Its just passing a string and a [ref]$object but no string for "value". The "value" I believe is what you use to retrieve the value found from the dictionary lookup.

Comment: It attempts to prevent "double-buffering" (ie. buffering inside the `$steppablePipeline` *and* in the proxy cmdlet), in case someone provides an `OutBuffer` value

Comment: What exactly is OutBuffer?

Comment: I'm confused because if I do: `$PSBoundParameters | gm` there is no OutBuffer property

Comment: Get-Help about_CommonParameters

Comment: But that's with the -OutBuffer param. This looks like its just appending a new key named "OutBuffer" to the $PSBoundParameters dictionary that didn't exists before.

Comment: You need to supply an `[int]` as an argument to `-OutBuffer`

Comment: Maybe I'm just being dumb here, but is `$PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer']`  the same as accessing the OutBuffer cmdlet param via `-OutBuffer`? If so how does that work? Seem like two different constructs to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What is OutBuffer

Per [@MathiasR.Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) in the comments documentation on `OutBuffer` is available by running: `Get-Help about_CommonParameters`[^](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters?view=powershell-6).

> -OutBuffer
>
> Alias: ob
>
> Determines the number of objects to accumulate in a buffer before
>      any objects are sent through the pipeline. If you omit this parameter,
>      objects are sent as they are generated.
>
> This resource management parameter is designed for advanced users.
>      When you use this parameter, Windows PowerShell does not call the 
>      next cmdlet in the pipeline until the number of objects generated
>      equals OutBuffer + 1. Thereafter, it sends all objects as they are
>      generated.

#### -OutBuffer vs $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer']

Regarding the difference between `$PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer']` and the parameter `OutBuffer`; there is none.  `$PSBoundParameters` is a dictionary holding all parameters passed by value into the current function/cmdlet.  You can find out more about this variable by running `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`[^](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6):

> $PSBoundParameters
>
> Contains a dictionary of the parameters that are passed to a script
>      or function and their current values. This variable has a value only
>      in a scope where parameters are declared, such as a script or function. 
>      You can use it to display or change the current values of parameters 
>      or to pass parameter values to another script or function.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> function Test {
>     param($a, $b)
>
>     # Display the parameters in dictionary format.
>     $PSBoundParameters
>
>     # Call the Test1 function with $a and $b.
>     test1 @PSBoundParameters
> }
> ```

#### More info on this scenario

The code you're showing looks like something from a [proxy function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand.create?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_ProxyCommand_Create_System_Management_Automation_CommandMetadata_).  As such you'll likely see the following line further down in the code:

```
$scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
```

Here the `$PSBoundParameters` hash table/dictionary is being passed to the command defined in variable `$wrappedCmd`, with all named values being passed as the parameter values of that function (i.e. each dictionary entry mapping its value to the command's parameter with the same name).  This is known as [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) (more on this by running `Get-Help about_splatting`):

> Splatting is a method of passing a collection of parameter values to a
>   command as unit. Windows PowerShell associates  each value in the
>   collection with a command parameter.  Splatted parameter values are
>   stored in named splatting  variables, which look like standard
>   variables, but begin with an At symbol (@) instead of a dollar sign
>   ($). The At symbol tells Windows PowerShell that you are passing a
>   collection of values, instead of a single value.
>
> Splatting makes your commands shorter and easier to read. You  can
>   re-use the splatting values in different command calls and use
>   splatting to pass parameter values from the $PSBoundParameters
>   automatic variable to other scripts and functions.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, you can also use splatting to
>   represent all parameters of a command.

#### Back to OutBuffer...  Why would you want to use it?

There's a good article on this here: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2013/07/16/common-parameter-part-4.aspx.  I've also attempted my own explanation below:

Typically it's used for performance gains.  Normally powershell works by fetching a single line/object and passing it all the way down the pipeline before fetching the next object/line, much like a foreach/iterator loop.  e.g.

```
Import-CSV 'abc.csv' | Export-CSV '123.csv'
```

Works a bit like this (pseudocode):

```
$reader = New-Object 'PseudoCode.CSVReader' -ArgumentList 'abc.csv'
$writer = New-Object 'PseudoCode.CSVReader' -ArgumentList '123.csv'
while ($data = $reader.ReadLine())
{
    $writer.WriteLine($data)
}
```

In some scenarios this is fine; it means you don't hold much in memory (normally) since you're grabbing and using data bit by bit.  However, sometimes you can get much better performance by working on things in larger chunks.  An analogy I often use is that of filling a sandpit by hand.  Given the process:

1. Pick up sand from the source pile
2. Carry it to the sandpit
3. Place it in the sandpit
4. Return to the source pile / repeat until the sandpit is full

Consider moving 1 grain at a time vs 1 bucket at a time vs 1 sandpit at a time.

- One grain at a time makes each individual trip easy, but would take a very long time to complete because of the number of round trips.
- One bucket at a time is still quite easy to carry for each trip; it still involves multiple trips, but is more feasible / would be completed after 100 or so trips; so is going to be more efficient.
- To pick up a whole sandpit's worth in one go (without machinery) would require more strength than the average person were capable off; so would fail.

Now the question is: what's the optimum bucket size.

Here our bucket's our outbuffer.

#### What about TryGetValue's Third Parameter?

You stated:

> It looks like it needs a 3rd argument: (string key, [ref]System.Object valueToBeStored)

There is no third parameter; parameters are:

- `string key`
- `[ref]System.Object valueToBeStored`

`Key` defines the name of the value to fetch.

`valueToBeStored` is the value we're fetching.  It's passed as a reference since this value gets populated with the value for the given key if such a value exists (in this case the function TryGetValue returns `true` as well as assigning the value).  If no such key exists in the dictionary the function returns `false` and the variable passed to parameter `valueToBeStored` keeps it's original value (i.e. `$null` in this case).  See [documentation on TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more.

If the `[ref]` confused you, this causes the parameter to be used as a reference variable.  You can read up on this via `get-help about_ref`[^](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-6):

> TOPIC
>
> about_Ref
>
> SHORT DESCRIPTION
>
> Describes how to create and use a reference variable type.
>
> LONG DESCRIPTION
>
> You can use the reference variable type to permit a method to change the
>   value of a variable that is passed to it.
>
> When the [ref] type is associated with an object, it returns a reference
>   to that object. If the reference is used with a method, the method can
>   refer to the object that was passed to it. If the object is changed within
>   the method, the change appears as a change in the value of the variable
>   when control returns to the calling method.
>
> To use referencing, the parameter must be a reference variable. If it is
>   not, an InvalidArgument exception is thrown.
>
> The parameters used in method invocations must match the type required 
>   by the methods.